# Depth of a binary search tree

Tags: arrays, data-structures, tree

Given a sorted array write a program to find a binary search tree with minimum depth, what is that depth?

I Know how to convert an array into a balanced BST, but how do u make the function to create a BST with minimum depth?

Comment: Do you only need to find the depth, or do you need to find the tree as well?

Comment: @AD.Net No. it something like log(array.length)(maybe +1).

Comment: @user2040251, of course, thanks. I was trying only with 6-7 numbers, missed the halving of each subarray

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a full binary tree with height `h`(`h` is the minimum number such that `2^h - 1` >= number of elements in your array). At this moment you can just ignore the input array. Obviously, this tree has minimum depth(any tree with smaller depth simply cannot have enough nodes to store all array elements).
2. Now you can fill this tree with array elements using a simple
   recursive approach:

   - Fill the left sub tree.
   - Put the smallest unused number into current node.
   - Fill the right sub tree.

Don't forget to remove `2^h - 1 - n` leaves before starting the traversal(where `n` is the input array size)(this step is necessary because the size of a full tree is `2^h - 1` but there are only `n` elements in the array).

An `O(n)` implementation of this algorithm is pretty straight-forward (you can explicitly build the tree, remove extra leaves and then traverse it, because the number of nodes in the tree is `O(n)`).

Comment: sorry for the late response, thanks u very much. Can u show what the C function will look like for the above implementation? I am new to c, and I am having trouble implementing it.